# I have facing below problem when scroll then render donut chart every time

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, flutter-layout

I have facing below problem when scroll then render donut chart every time.

This below Renderer Param remove then not facing this problem but i have required donut chart.

```
defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(
              arcWidth: 60,
              arcRendererDecorators: [charts.ArcLabelDecorator()])
          ),
```

Hereby, I am attaching **Donut Chart** code & Image:-

```
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_basf_hk_app/model/LinearSales.dart';

class PieOutsideLabelChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  PieOutsideLabelChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  /// Creates a [PieChart] with sample data and no transition.
  factory PieOutsideLabelChart.withSampleData(List<LinearSales> data,
      bool isAnimation) {
    return new PieOutsideLabelChart(
      _createSampleData(data),
      // Disable animations for image tests.
      animate: isAnimation,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: new charts.PieChart(seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(
          arcWidth: 60,
          arcRendererDecorators: [charts.ArcLabelDecorator()])
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Create one series with sample hard coded data.
  static List<charts.Series<LinearSales, int>> _createSampleData(List<LinearSales> data) {
    print('=========PIE==========_createSampleData=====');
    return [
      new charts.Series<LinearSales, int>(
        id: 'Sales',
        domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
        colorFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.color,
        labelAccessorFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => '${sales.sales}',
      )
    ];
  }
}
```

[image: I have attached output image below.]

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the type of help your looking for, thus,

Check out this more commonly used chart plugin called syncfusion_flutter_charts.

https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts#-readme-tab-